# How to Write a Function in Python When Variables Haven't Been Defined Prior?

Tags: python, pandas, list, function

Without writing a function, I get the correct output from this:

`import pandas as pd`

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=none) # Opens the CSV file
df2 = df.values.tolist() # Transforms rows into lists

print(df2)
```

Out:

`[[434, 324, 324], [6324, 3274, 3433]]`

However, I'm trying to write a function to do the same thing (opens the file and returns the values in a list).

I tried:

```
def retrieve_data(*args):
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=none)
    df2 = df.values.tolist()
    return df2

retrieve_data(df2)
```

But this returns the error that `df2` hasn't been defined.

How can I edit the function so that it opens the data and stores the values as a list to `df2`?

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want this at all

Comment: Define a function which doesn't take a parameter (and call it without one). The parameter (`args`) isn't used anyway.

Comment: @MichaelButscher this sort of works, e.g. `retrieve_data(df2)` returns the whole list. But, if I want to do e.g. `retrieve_data(df2[1])` to get that element, it won't work. Any ideas how to enable this?

Comment: You can either give only the `1` as argument and process it in the function or select the element after the function call.

Comment: In the first lines of code you posted, you assign the result of a function (e.g. `tolist()`) to a variable. Why don't you do the same with your own function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the df2 is not needed in the function call as it is not defined at that point. So I have made some changes to the code that works.

```
import pandas as pd

def retrieve_data():
  df = pd.read_csv('./test.csv', header=None)
  df2 = df.values.tolist()
  return df2

lst = retrieve_data()
print(lst[:1]) #print only part of list as needed
```

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity, how could you return e.g. the first two elements from the list? In my example, I only showed two lists but indeed there are many. Using `print(retrieve_data())` prints all of them, and `print(retrive_data[:1]` to get the first two only doesn't work. @Ananth

Comment: @HelpNeeded3 I have made the update to the code now. The code will return last element only and you can retrieve as many elements from list as possible the same way.